# How to reduce duplicate gems with RVM and Bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I work at a company where I develop on over 10 different ruby and rails apps.  Between these ten apps, I have 3 ruby versions and 7 gemsets (total).  There are certain utility gems (like `pry`, `colored`, `git-up`, `hookup`, etc.), which I would like to be able to install once (per ruby — if necessary) and have access to across gemsets within the same ruby versions.

I tried installing these gems into the 'global' gemset for each ruby version, however, once I `cd` into a project and the gemset changes (same ruby version though), I no longer have access to the gem's executable.  I have to reinstall the gem in the specific gemset.

I just get the feeling that I am missing something as I have so many duplicate gems installed on my system.  What are the best practices around this desired behavior?  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna install a gem per ruby, you need to do a `gem install pry` for instance. That will install the gem on the ruby level. After that you can require that in your Rails app, for instance on the `boot.rb` file.
I am not sure how rvm deals with gemsets. If what they do is change the entire folder reference of the `gem` command, then you wont be able to do that. I would need to install those gems for every gemset, which is a PITA.

On my workflow, I dont need gemsets, as I have bundler. So I use rbenv to install and change ruby versions, and let bundler deals with gems for a project. Like so, I can install a gem, globally per ruby, and it works.

Comment: I've been an RVM user for years but it seems rbenv enables the desired behavior.  Thanks!